# LINQ List<structure> orderby.thenby not sorting

Tags: linq, list, sql-order-by

I have a structure,

```
public struct temp1
{
    public string field1;
    public string field2;
    public string field3;
    public int field3;
    public int field4;
    public double field5;
    public string field6;
    public string field7;
    public string field8;
    public int field9;
}
```

then some code ************

I populate the list through a .csv file and now need to orderby.thenby

I am using,

```
temp1 = temp1.OrderBy(a => a.field3)
             .ThenBy(a => a.field4)
             .ThenBy(a => a.field6)
             .ThenBy(a => a.field7)
             .ThenBy(a => a.field5).ToList()
```

I then export to excel, i see that the first 3 columns are correctly sorted, but then the sorting stops for the other 2. I am stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not expecting a string type to be sorted like an int?

Comment: Can you provide a small example of a data set and what results you're seeing?

Comment: AAXX, 3, 17, P, 2014,  XX0011222111 -50;
AAXX, 6, 19, P, 2013,  XX0011222111 500;
ABXX, 3, 20, P, 2014,  BE0011222333 18;
BAXX, 3, 21, C, 2014,  FG0011224125 210;
BBXX, 3, 21, P, 2014,  KK0011226258 6;

Comment: Dev.Jaap. That was my first instinct, but when I saw the first column which is String was sorted alphabetically I discarded the notion.

Comment: @user1449792: Your struct and the data you posted don't seem to match up at all. The struct you posted has a different number of fields than the csv you're posting, and also has a duplicate "field3". Can you edit your post with a small reproducible example? Otherwise it'll be hard to help.

Comment: I thought I could be selective in terms of what I sort by. I dont need to sort by all fields. Ill take a few screenshots

Comment: You certainly can, but its hard to show someone else what you're trying to do without the full picture, or a reproducible example using the subset of data you're referring to.

Comment: snippet of code,
        public struct options
        {
            public string optionsExcCode;
            public string optionsCode;
            public string optionsSTK;
            public double optionsMnt;
            public double optionsYr;
            public double optionsStrike;
            public string optionsType;
            public string optionsVersion;
            public string optionsIsin;
            public double optionsPosNet;
        }
        public List<options> myOptionsPos = new List<options>();

[IMG]http://i39.tinypic.com/ncxw1i.png[/IMG]

Comment: [IMG]http://i39.tinypic.com/o7slc9.png[/IMG]

Comment: Have you checked if it is sorted incorrectly before exporting to excel?